# How to convert multiple values in Excel cell

Tags: excel, regex, vba, excel-formula

I'm looking for a formula that re-arranges values in excel cells.
The cells contain full names (at least one, up to 20) in the format of "last name + name(s)" but this must be convert into the following format:

1.- First letter of first name, follow by a blank space.
2.- Last name

An example can be found below.

I know I could simple use replace function, but it would be great if this might be possible to achieve via excel formulas.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Have a look on here - there are many examples showing the use of left(), mid(), right(), len() and find().

Comment: What if someone has a [Double lastname](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-barrelled_name), like [Andrew Lloyd Webber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andrew_Lloyd_Webber) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this UDF.

```
Option Explicit

Function ExtractName(cellRng As Range)
Dim regex As Object, mc As Object, i As Long, str As String, arr
Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.regexp")
regex.ignorecase = False
regex.Global = True

arr = Split(cellRng.Value, "|")
str = ""
For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
    regex.Pattern = "^[\w-]+\s\b."
    Set mc = regex.Execute(arr(i))
    str = str & Split(mc(0), " ")(1) & " " & Split(mc(0), " ")(0) & "|"
Next i

ExtractName = Left(str, Len(str) - 1)
End Function
```

[image]

Comment: Note that in the pattern `[\w-]` matches word character and "-". You can add any other character in there to match text before the first space in the full name. This function will fail if there are double last names as suggested by Luuk in comment on the question.

Comment: To avoid error in case of double names, we can improve this function to check number of spaces. First, then we will have to trim the full name which will give us only the spaces between the two words and not the last one before |

Comment: Hello Naresh, thanks for your help. You function did the trick. Good thing is there is no double names in all the records, so it shouldn't be an issue. Thanks again.

Comment: @GTGabaaron .. Happy to learn that.:) Also, [please accept an answer with a tick on the left of it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=%20To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A%20%201%20Choose,un-accept%20the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.%20More%20) if you don't want to wait for more answers.

Answer (score 4):

Since the strings can be so long, I would use `FILTERXML` and `LET` if you have the newest version of Excel rather than keep having to repeat things like `LEFT`, `LEN`, or `FIND`.

For example, if the data is always seperated by a "|" and only comes in the form "Last_Name First_Name (possible Mid_Initial)|", then you can use something like:

```
=LET(x, FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(I1, "|", "</s><s>")&"</s></t>", "//s"),
y, TRIM(LEFT(RIGHT(x, LEN(x)-SEARCH(" ",x)),1)),
z, TRIM(LEFT(x, SEARCH(" ",x))),
LEFT(CONCAT(y&" "&z&", "), LEN(CONCAT(y&" "&z&", "))-2))
```

[image]

Comment: Hello and thanks for your help. It seems that even though I'm using Office 265 ProPlus the LET function is not available, it seems that needs to be changed from semi-annual channel but I don't have privileges to do that.